# Transfer Existing domain to Azure with billing

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I already have a domain with a non-azure domain provider (arvixe.com to be specific). I want to completely get rid of my current registrar and move to Azure fully including hosting and billing of my domain. I cannot find a way to do this. There are few powershell scripts around but none is working in my case.

Comment: See my answer, though I may be able to provide something more specific if you post a link to the script(s) you've tried and indicate in what way they're not working.

Answer (score 0):

Note that transfer of domains may be restricted for 60 days after registration and you must make sure that the domain is not [locked at the original registrar](https://www.icann.org/resources/pages/locked-2013-05-03-en).

In this [this MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/271731d8-6cd2-443b-b861-ee4ee30e34e9/transfer-domain-registration-to-azure?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) dated March 15, 2018 a Microsoft moderator remarked that transfer is only supported for **`.com`**, **`.org`**,  and **`.net`** top-level domains.

> <sub>See the answer by Omar JG/SadiqhAhmed-MSFT:</sub>
>
> **Scope: ONLY support Domain transfer for .com, org,.net**
>
> It is now possible to use PowerShell to transfer a domain purchased outside of Azure to Azure. Here's the PowerShell script:
>
> ```
> $ResourceName = "<domain>" #user's domain (constoso.com)
> $PropertiesObject = @{
>     'Consent' = @{
>         'AgreementKeys' = @("DNPA","DNTA");
>         'AgreedBy' = '<ip_address>'; #user's IP address (192.168.1.1)
>         'AgreedAt' = '<time>'; #roughly the current time (2017-13-05T12:25:30.6850404Z)
>     };
>     'authCode' = '<auth_code>'; #code obtained from their current provider in order to transfer out the domain
>     'Privacy' = 'true';
>     'autoRenew' = 'true';
> }
> ```

I have not found any recent indication that the scope of this has yet expanded.

Comment: Thanks Trevor for the reply, but I'm getting 500 error when I try to execute the script from powershell (both local and cloud shell). Other than 500 error there is no real information in the message. In fact it is typical asp.net web.config issue page I'm getting.

Comment: @Vinit Yadav — Is your domain in one of the supported top-level domains.  Arvixe offers many TLD's besides .com, .org, and .net.  I only ask because of the 'xyz' in the original version of this post.

Comment: Yes, my domain is .com domain.