# Getting 'The parameter domain.Properties.Consent has an invalid value.' when trying to transfer a domain into Azure

Tags: azure, azure-dns

We are getting '**The parameter domain.Properties.Consent has an invalid value.**' when trying to transfer a domain into our Azure account. We are using ARM templates for the deployment. No matter what we do, we can not figure out what is invalid with the consent property.

We tried what was suggested in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134174/3117194), but get a 'An error has occurred' error in PSH when trying it that way.

Here is the content of the arm resource. Can someone help with what is not correct?

```
{
"name": "hxxxxxr.net",
"type": "Microsoft.DomainRegistration/domains",
"apiVersion": "2015-02-01",
"dependsOn": [
  "Microsoft.Network/dnszones/hxxxxxr.net"
],
"location": "global",
"Properties": {
  "Consent": {
    "AgreementKeys": [
      "DNPA",
      "DNTA"
    ],
    "AgreedBy": "76.x.x.x",
    "AgreedAt": "2020-01-16T21:18:00Z"
  },
  "ContactAdmin": {
    "AddressMailing": {
      "Address1": "111 xxx",
      "Address2": "Suite 6",
      "City": "Hxxx",
      "Country": "US",
      "PostalCode": "76xxx",
      "State": "TX"
    },
    "Email": "DomainAdmin@hxxxxxr.net",
    "Fax": "",
    "JobTitle": "",
    "NameFirst": "Domain",
    "NameLast": "Admin",
    "NameMiddle": "",
    "Organization": "Mxxx",
    "Phone": "+1.8xxx1234"
  },
  "ContactBilling": {
    "AddressMailing": {
      "Address1": "111 xxx",
      "Address2": "Suite 6",
      "City": "Hxxx",
      "Country": "US",
      "PostalCode": "76xxx",
      "State": "TX"
    },
    "Email": "DomainAdmin@hxxxxxr.net",
    "Fax": "",
    "JobTitle": "",
    "NameFirst": "Domain",
    "NameLast": "Admin",
    "NameMiddle": "",
    "Organization": "Mxxx",
    "Phone": "+1.8xxx1234"
  },
  "ContactRegistrant": {
    "AddressMailing": {
      "Address1": "111 xxx",
      "Address2": "Suite 6",
      "City": "Hxxx",
      "Country": "US",
      "PostalCode": "76xxx",
      "State": "TX"
    },
    "Email": "DomainAdmin@hxxxxxr.net",
    "Fax": "",
    "JobTitle": "",
    "NameFirst": "Domain",
    "NameLast": "Admin",
    "NameMiddle": "",
    "Organization": "Mxxx",
    "Phone": "+1.8xxx1234"
  },
  "ContactTech": {
    "AddressMailing": {
      "Address1": "111 xxx",
      "Address2": "Suite 6",
      "City": "Hxxx",
      "Country": "US",
      "PostalCode": "76xxx",
      "State": "TX"
    },
    "Email": "DomainAdmin@hxxxxxr.net",
    "Fax": "",
    "JobTitle": "",
    "NameFirst": "Domain",
    "NameLast": "Admin",
    "NameMiddle": "",
    "Organization": "Mxxx",
    "Phone": "+1.8xxx1234"
  },
  "privacy": false,
  "autoRenew": false,
  "targetDnsType": "AzureDns",
  "dnsZoneId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/dnsZones', 'hxxxxxr.net')]",
  "authCode": "Zig9zxxxxx"
}
```

Comment: Just me and the crickets hanging out here...